# Change meta box when the page's template is changed

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

For my WordPress theme I have a custom portfolio post type and a portfolio page template to display them. What I want to do is add a meta box to the edit page area, but only when the page has the portfolio template.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
function my_portfolio_meta_box_cb($post) {
     $template = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);
     if ($template == 'portfolio.php') {
         add_meta_box(........);
     }
}
```

Hook this via the `register_meta_box_cb` arg when registering the post type or in your manually via `add_meta_boxes-portfolio` hook.

Comment: sorry for my english, how can we put this in a select option onchenge
it meen that when qe choise the template the add_meta_box apear just in that moment.
thanks
h.